# Keep getting Cross-Site Request Forgery error using Ueberauth

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ueberauth

I am using Phoenix version 1.3 and the UeberAuth "~> 0.6". I am currently receiving a CRSF error that I don't think should be happening, but I may well be making an error.

In my router.ex file, I have the following:

```
scope "/auth", DiscussWeb do
    pipe_through :browser
    get "/:provider", AuthController, :request
    get "/:provider/callback", AuthController, :callback
end
```

In my controller file, the callback is as follows:

```
def callback(conn, params) do
    callback_t(conn, params)
    conn
    |> put_flash(:info, "Github Authenticate?")
    |> redirect(to: Routes.topic_path(conn, :index))
end

defp callback_t(conn, params) do
    IO.puts "+++"
    IO.inspect(conn.assigns)
    IO.puts "+++"
    IO.inspect(params)
    IO.puts "+++"
end
```

In the browser, I do get redirected to GitHub to login. However, I get the following response:

```
debug] Processing with DiscussWeb.AuthController.callback/2
  Parameters: %{"code" => "908a69a812c17af0ab0b", "provider" => "github"}
  Pipelines: [:browser]
+++
%{
  ueberauth_failure: %Ueberauth.Failure{
    errors: [
      %Ueberauth.Failure.Error{
        message: "Cross-Site Request Forgery attack",
        message_key: :csrf_attack
      }
    ],
    provider: :github,
    strategy: Ueberauth.Strategy.Github
  }
}
+++
%{"code" => "908a69a812c17af0ab0b", "provider" => "github"}
+++
[info] Sent 302 in 4ms
[info] GET /
```

Is this expected? It seems like I am actually logged in because if I try the same thing in the browser, I do not have to login to GitHub. However, there is also a CRSF failure that is happening that I'm not sure how to deal with and there is no way to get the info I need from the conn.assigns variable.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am facing the same issue as you, 100% same. So I tried OAuth with Google API and it worked. I created the dev account and I got the redirected and no CSRF issue. So there is something with the GitHub config I presume. As for Github I tried adding strategies `github: {Ueberauth.Strategy.Github, [ignores_csrf_attack: true]}` but no help. Also I tried to set POST instead of GET but again no luck. Take this repo as a testing area to see how it works [Überauth Example](https://github.com/ueberauth/ueberauth_example). Hope it helps a bit. I will get back if I find fix for Github. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Update the in the mix.exs file `ueberauth_github` to **latest** version like so `{:ueberauth_github, "~> 0.8"}`, and then run `mix.deps update` (you might do a clean start with `mix.deps clean`). After this I authenticated with Github without any issues or additional strategies. I used the app in the comment I left on your question before I found the solution.

Comment: For some reason for me not even `0.8` worked but the currently still unreleased `0.8.1` did. So `{:ueberauth_github, github: "ueberauth/ueberauth_github", branch: "master"}`

Comment: @KonstantinK not working anymore

Comment: Still not working in 2023

Answer (score 0):

I had to use an older versions of Ueberauth and Ueberauth_Github to make it work properly:

My **deps** in the **mix.exs** file:

```
  {:ueberauth, "~> 0.6.0"},
  {:ueberauth_github, "~> 0.7.0"},
```